# Error handling Scala : Future For Comprehension

Tags: scala, error-handling, playframework, future

I want to do error handling in my play scala web application.

My application talks to the data base to fetch some rows, it follows following flow.

1. First call to db to fetch some data
2. Use the data in first call to fetch other data from db
3. Form a response using the data received from last two db calls.

Below is my pseudocode.

```
 def getResponse(name: String)
      (implicit ctxt: ExecutionContext): Future[Response] = {
    for {
        future1 <- callFuture1(name)
        future2 <- callFuture2(future1.data)
        future3 <- callFuture3(future1.data, future2.data)
    }  yield future3
  }
```

Every method in the comprehension above returns a future, the signature of these methods are as below.

```
private def callFuture1(name: String)
  (implicit ctxt: ExecutionContext): Future[SomeType1] {...}

private def callFuture2(keywords: List[String])
  (implicit ctxt: ExecutionContext): Future[SomeType2] {...}

private def callFuture3(data: List[SomeType3], counts: List[Int])
  (implicit ctxt: ExecutionContext): Future[Response] {...}
```

How shall I do error/failure handling, in the following situation

- When callFuture1 fails to fetch data from database. I want to return
  a appropriate error response with error message. Since callFuture2
  only gets executed after callFuture1. I dont want to execute
  callFuture2 if callFuture1 has failed/erred and would want to return
  error message immediately. (Same thing for callFuture2 and
  callFuture3)

--edit--

I am trying to return an appropriate Error Response from getResponse() method, when either of the callFuture fails and not proceed to subsequent futureCalls.

I tried the following, based on Peter Neyens answer, but gave me an runtime error..

```
 def getResponse(name: String)
      (implicit ctxt: ExecutionContext): Future[Response] = {
    for {
        future1 <- callFuture1(name) recoverWith {
         case e:Exception => return Future{Response(Nil,Nil,e.getMessage)}
        }
        future2 <- callFuture2(future1.data)
        future3 <- callFuture3(future1.data, future2.data)
    }  yield future3
  }
```

Runtime error i get

```
ERROR] [08/31/2015 02:09:45.011] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] (scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl)
[error] a.a.ActorSystemImpl - Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]
scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl: null
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use the [`Future.recoverWith`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#recoverWith%5BU%3E:T%5D(pf:PartialFunction%5BThrowable,scala.concurrent.Future%5BU%5D%5D)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BU%5D) function, to customize the exception if the `Future` failed.

```
val failed = Future.failed(new Exception("boom"))
failed recoverWith {
  case e: Exception => Future.failed(new Exception("A prettier error message", e)
}
```

This will result in a slightly uglier for comprehension :

```
for {
  future1 <- callFuture1(name) recoverWith {
               case npe: NullPointerException =>
                 Future.failed(new Exception("how did this happen in Scala ?", npe))
               case e: IllegalArgumentException =>
                 Future.failed(new Exception("better watch what you give me", e))
               case t: Throwable =>
                 Future.failed(new Exception("pretty message A", t))
             }
  future2 <- callFuture2(future1.data) recoverWith {
               case e: Exception => Future.failed(new Exception("pretty message B", e))
             }
  future3 <- callFuture3(future1.data, future2.data) recoverWith {
               case e: Exception => Future.failed(new Exception("pretty message C", e))
             }
} yield future3
```

Note that you could also define your own exceptions to use instead of `Exception`, if you want to add more information than just an error message.

If you don't want fine grained control to set a different error message depending on the `Throwable` in the failed `Future` (like with `callFuture1`), you could enrich `Future` using an implicit class to set a custom error message somewhat simpler:

```
implicit class ErrorMessageFuture[A](val future: Future[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def errorMsg(error: String): Future[A] = future.recoverWith {
    case t: Throwable => Future.failed(new Exception(error, t))
  }
}
```

Which you could use like :

```
for {
  future1 <- callFuture1(name) errorMsg "pretty A"
  future2 <- callFuture2(future1.data) errorMsg "pretty B"
  future3 <- callFuture3(future1.data, future2.data) errorMsg "pretty C"
} yield future3
```

In both cases, using `errorMsg` or `recoverWith` directly, you still rely on `Future`, so if a `Future` fails the following `Futures` will not be executed and you can directly use the error message inside the failed `Future`.

You didn't specify how you would like to handle the error messages. If for example you want to use the error message to create a different `Response` you could use `recoverWith` or `recover`.

```
future3 recover { case e: Exception =>
  val errorMsg = e.getMessage
  InternalServerError(errorMsg)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. it was helpful. i am still not sure if this solves my problem. 1) Using the approach 1, (without using implicit class),  when i recoverwith Future.failed(new Exception()), an exception is thrown and my execution does not proceed. I am trying to return an appropriate ResponseMessage when any of the futurecall fails, without proceeding to subsequent futurecalls( i shall update the question to make it more clear)

Comment: Future.fail(new Exception(...)) causes the execution to throw an exception. Instead i want to Return an appropriate error message when something fails/errors in futurecall.

Comment: Try something like the last code example in my answer.

Comment: Not sure, what you mean, returning InternalServerError causes type mismatch, because the method is expecting Future of Type Response.

Comment: I'm not sure which `Response` type you mean, but try replacing `InternalServerError(errorMsg)` with your `Response(Nil, Nil, errorMsg)`.

Comment: Note that you should not create a `Response` inside a `recover` or `recoverWith` **in** the for comprehension itself, because in that case the `Response` will be passed to the following `callFutureX`.

Comment: returning Future{IntenralServor(errorMsg)} instead of Future{Response(Nil, Nil, errorMessage)} gives types mismatch compilation error( which makes sense). The getResponse method is expecting return type to be Future[Response] and i am not trying to return Future[InternalServerError]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88402/discussion-between-peter-neyens-and-konquestor).

Answer (score 6):

Say `future1`, `future2` and `future3` throw `Throwable` exceptions named `Future1Exception`, `Future2Exception` and `Future3Exception`, respectively. Then you can return appropriate error `Response` from `getResponse()` method as follows:

```
def getResponse(name: String)
             (implicit ctxt: ExecutionContext): Future[Response] = {
  (for {
    future1 <- callFuture1(name)
    future2 <- callFuture2(future1.data)
    future3 <- callFuture3(future1.data, future2.data)
  } yield future3).recover {
    case e: Future1Exception =>
      // build appropriate Response(...)

    case e: Future2Exception =>
      // build appropriate Response(...)

    case e: Future3Exception =>
      // build appropriate Response(...)
  }
}
```

According to documentation [`Future.recover`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/concurrent/Future.html#recover[U%3E:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U])

> Creates a new future that will handle any matching throwable that this
>    future might contain.