# Issue of Exception Leakage

Tags: scala, exception

I have a doubt regarding exception leak.

```
 case class CustomException(message: String) extends RuntimeException(message)

   def listOfFut(list: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
          def handleFut(list: List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
            if (list.isEmpty) throw CustomException("Test")
            else Future.successful(list)
          }
          for {
            myList <- Future.successful(list)
            result <- handleFut(myList)
          } yield result
        }
```

I have done same thing like above snippet but got the feedback it might leak the exception without wrapping it.
Basically, `throw CustomException("Test")` might leak the exception.

Comment: Can you please let me know what exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: Actually, I have done the same thing. But when I am doing throw CustomException. Our client has said it might leak exception. So, I didn't get it how an exception is leaking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error handling Scala : Future For Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292750/error-handling-scala-future-for-comprehension)

Comment: @Piro This is not duplicate first. This question does not answer exception leakage.

Comment: What do you mean by "leak the exception" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I do not see any case of Exception leakage as if the list is empty, it will terminate abnormally with the custom exception. One of the approaches that you could follow is using as Either to wrap the exception in Left and the correct output in Right.

But this will involve changing the method signature

```
def listOfFut(list: List[Int]): Future[Either[Exception,List[Int]]] = {

  def handleFut(list: List[Int]): Future[Either[Exception,List[Int]]] = {
    if (list.isEmpty) Future.successful(Left(CustomException("Test")))
    else Future.successful(Right(list))
  }

  for {
    myList <- Future.successful(list)
    result <- handleFut(myList)
  } yield result
}

listOfFut(List()) onComplete {
  case Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback, meaning = $value")
    value match {
      case Right(output) =>
        println(s"Output is ${output}")
      case Left(ex) =>
        println(s"Exception is ${ex}")
    }
  case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
}
```

Please do let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to `it might leak the exception without wrapping it` is handle the exception  instead of throwing it. You should fail the future:

```
def handleFut(list: List[Int]): Future[Either[Exception,List[Int]]] = {
    if (list.isEmpty) Future.failed(new CustomException("Test"))
    else Future.successful(Right(list))
}
```